# Target-Action in swift not respecting default parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a UIBarButtonItem that i would like to display a drawer-menu.

I've implemented a function that looks like this:

```
func showMenu(animated: Bool = true) {
     self.rootViewController.presentViewController(self.menuViewController, animated: animated, completion: nil)
}
```

This is implemented in a class called `HomeCoordinator`

Now, I've added a target and action to my UIBarButtonItem like so:

```
    s.menuItem.target = self
    s.menuItem.action = #selector(HomeCoordinator.showMenu)
```

When the `showMenu` function is executed via the barbuttonitem, the animated param is false. Why is this? Can I change this without changing function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with that.

Issue A is related to the core of your question: why isn't the default parameter applied. This is because Objective-C doesn't support default parameters and `UIBarButtonItem` is an Objective-C class. It doesn't know anything about the default parameter you assigned in Swift. The default parameter is only injected if you call the function from within Swift.

Issue B is related to the signature of Cocoa (target) actions. You can usually omit the argument, but actions you assign to Cocoa controls always get the `sender` as the first argument (the object responsible for invoking the action), like so:

```
func showMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { ... }
```

All actions should follow this signature.

So you probably should separate the two:

```
func showMenu(animated: Bool = true) {
  self.rootViewController.presentViewController(self.menuViewController,
                                                animated: animated, 
                                                completion: nil)
}

func onShowMenu(_ sender: Any) {
  showMenu()
}

s.menuItem.target = self
s.menuItem.action = #selector(HomeCoordinator.onShowMenu)
```

Comment: You are slightly incorrect. You can *always* omit the `sender` argument on iOS. You can also add a second argument `...forEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Comment: You are right, one should not omit the second argument on iOS. I don't think you should omit any of the arguments. Whether that is legal is an implementation detail of the C ABI, objc_msg_send and the Swift bridge. I'm pretty sure it is not a guarantee and shouldn't be usually done. It is better to declare the action the way it is invoked on the calling site.

Comment: OK, to correct myself - you are right :-) Parameter omissions are explicitly allowed: `In contrast to the AppKit framework, where an action method may have only one or perhaps two valid signatures, the UIKit framework allows three different forms of action selector ` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH12-SW44

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do. IBActions have a specific signature. They either have no parameters, a sender (of type AnyObject, I believe), or a sender and a triggering UIEvent. The 3 signatures look like this:

```
@IBAction func doSomething()
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton)
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

### EDIT:

The method signatures above are copied directly from the UIControl documentation from the latest version of Xcode. It looks like they weren't updated for Swift 3. They should really be:

```
@IBAction func doSomething()
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton)
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

(As pointed out by rmaddy. The underscore means the sender parameter is not named.)

You are declaring a selector with no parameters, and yet your showMenu function has a BOOL parameter. You can't pass an arbitrary object to an IBAction - it must be the sender that triggers the action (A UIControl, usually a button.)

Try changing your selector to

```
s.menuItem.action = #selector(HomeCoordinator.showMenu(_:))
```

but I don't think it will work.

Comment: If you use that `#selector` it won't match any of the method signatures you mention. You would need to add `_` before `sender` in the last two signatures.

Comment: The methods I put in my answer are right out of Apple's iOS documentation on UIControl. Looks like they have not been updated for Swift 3. (My suggested selector in the bottom of part of my answer follows the syntax you describe, although I expect it to crash at runtime because the sender type won't match the Bool type of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItem` action *should* only accept a selector that references a method that takes an instance of `UIBarButtonItem` as a parameter.

```
func methodName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    ...
}


#selector(ClassName.methodName(_:))
```

Other parameter types may appear to be legal (`Bool`, `Int`), however they are likely not useful.